# How to get the text color of a QLabel?

Tags: qt, colors, qtgui, qlabel

I'm wondering how to get the text color of a specific `QLabel`. I'm setting text color earlier in my code an need to read it out again later to determine which action to take...

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use:

```
QLabel::palette()
```

To get the palette of this widget. Once you have the palette I guess you could retrieve the color via:

```
ColorRole r = QPalette::Text;
const QBrush & QPalette::brush(r);
```

Once you have the QBrush you can simply use:

```
const QColor & QBrush::color() const
```

Comment: `buttonText` is bad advise because it can be different from label's text. The most short correct answer is `label->palette()->color(QPalette::WindowText)`.